# How to override Spring 3.1 @PropertySource to set IgnoreResourceNotFound & IgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, properties, configuration

Having this class to override an already set @PropertySource in another Config class.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:${env.placeholder}/app.properties" })
public class PropertyOverrideConfig {

}
```

But whenever the file or placeholder is missing, its failing the context loading. I need to set the following flags to that annotation loaded property, so that it will skip, if its not able to find the property.

```
        setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
        setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
```

*Question1: What would be the appropriate way to set these flags for the @PropertySource?*

**Updates:**
Tried adding a @Bean to the same class without that annotation referring [this](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/) page, it ain't picking the property file either. I don't have an xml configuration.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties() {
     final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer pspc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();

     Resource[] resources = new ClassPathResource[ ] { 
                  new ClassPathResource( "classpath:${env.placeholder}/app.properties" ) };

     pspc.setLocations( resources );
     pspc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
     pspc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
     return pspc;
}
```

*Question2: I am sure I'm missing something, but couldn't figure out what it is, any help would be great.*

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer instances registered? Maybe you should make the `@Bean` annotated method that returns PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer  static (as java doc for `@Bean` recommends)

Comment: Thanks @BorisTreukhov , I missed the static when posting. Meanwhile, what would happen, if I have same `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` already registered bean on a different Config??

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but you can have several PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurers(and specify them different placeholder prefixes/suffixes) - maybe there is another placeholder configurer which complaints about unresolvable placeholders

Comment: As for the missing file I think it's rather generated by the property source framework and not by the post processor.

Comment: Maybe you should add the actual error messages you get in the different situations.

Comment: I didn't get any errors when I have the @Bean definition, its just not using the property file i mentioned in it. There are no errors except the one which is failing to find the property in that app.properties.

Comment: unfortunately IgnoreUnresolvableNestedPlaceholders property is not a part of PropertySource. to be able to change this property for your environment you can Autowire ConfigurableEnvironment bean into your PropertyOverrideConfig config class and call `setIgnoreUnresolvableNestedPlaceholders(true);` (For example as part of post-construction.)

Answer (score 4):

I think I finally figured out the answer for the Question1:

**How to set Ignore flags for properties added through `@PropertySource`?**

> Its not there in Spring still, its been proposed as an Minor
>   Improvement. Hopefully will be able to see an additional attribute
>   added to the annotation soon in future release.
>
> **[SPR-8371](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8371)**

Still not sure about the way to accomplish the scenario mentioned and no answer for Question2.

Comment: There's also [SPR-10325](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10325): "Allow for ignoreResourceNotFound on @PropertySource", vote for it!

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution, but a workaround, if you have to stick to Spring 3: use a dummy default, which exists, i.e. in your case:

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:${env.placeholder:dummy}/app.properties" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `classpath:`, it is not needed when using `ClassPathResource`:

```
new ClassPathResource( "classpath:${env.placeholder}/app.properties" ) };
```